# Translate docker run command to docker compose

Tags: docker, gitlab, docker-compose, gitlab-omnibus

I'm losing my mind a little here, I think I've translated the command correctly,  but I'm getting an error when I try `docker-compose up -d`

Here's my command, this works - without failure:

```
sudo docker run -i \
    --hostname localhost \
    --publish 444:443 --publish 8080:8080 --publish 23:22 \
    --name gitlab \
    --restart always \
    --volume /home/admin/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab \
    --volume /home/admin/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab \
    --volume /home/admin/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab \
    --volume /home/admin/gitlab/logs/reconfigure:/var/log/gitlab/reconfigure \
    -e VIRTUAL_HOST=git.example.com
    -e VIRTUAL_PORT=8080
gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
```

Here's my `docker-compose.yml` file, which isn't working

```
gitlab:
  image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest'
  restart: always
  container_name: gitlab
  ports:
    - '8080:80'
    - '23:22'
    - '444:443'
  volumes:
    - '/home/admin/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab'
    - '/home/admin/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab'
    - '/home/admin/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab'
    - '/home/admin/gitlab/logs/reconfigure:/var/log/gitlab/reconfigure'
  environment:
    - VIRTUAL_HOST=git.example.ca
    - VIRTUAL_PORT=8080
```

Can you see something that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Telling us what error you get would make things much easier. If I had to guess: don't quote the image name and mounts, use double quotes for the ports. Rest looks ok to me.

Comment: Thanks Erik, there's no error it just returns 502. I'll try that.

Comment: State compose version and paste the compete error log here

Comment: Try pasting into https://composerize.com and see how it compares

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `hostname: localhost` as you do it in docker run to have

```
gitlab:
  image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest'
  restart: always
  container_name: gitlab
  hostname: localhost
  ports:
    - '8080:80'
    - '23:22'
    - '444:443'
  volumes:
    - '/home/admin/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab'
    - '/home/admin/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab'
    - '/home/admin/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab'
    - '/home/admin/gitlab/logs/reconfigure:/var/log/gitlab/reconfigure'
  environment:
    - VIRTUAL_HOST=git.example.ca
    - VIRTUAL_PORT=8080
```